# How to use UDP with Unity methods

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I created a Cube object and attached this script.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CubeMove : MonoBehaviour {
    void Start () {
    }

    void Update () {
    }

    public void Move () {
        Vector3 moveVector = new Vector3(10, 0, 0);
        transform.Translate(moveVector);
    }
}
```

I wanted to use UDP to control cube move, so I created UDPManager.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

public class UDPManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    static UdpClient udp;
    Thread thread;

    public GameObject cube;
    public CubeMove cubemove;

    void Start ()
    {
        udp = new UdpClient(12345);
        cubemove = cube.GetComponent<CubeMove>();
        thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadMethod));
        thread.Start();
    }

    void Update ()
    {
    }

    void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        udp.Close();
        thread.Abort();
    }

    private void ThreadMethod()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

            byte[] receiveBytes = udp.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint); 
            string returnData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes);
            Debug.Log(returnData);
            if (returnData == "1\n") {
                cube.SendMessage ("Move");
                // or
                cubemove.Move();

            }
        }
    } 
}
```

but these doesn't works with below errors.

```
- SendMessage can only be called from the main thread.
- get_transform can only be called from the main thread.
```

Can I call unity methods when I receive udp command?

Comment: neither of the answers below worked for me, but the two scripts here did: https://forum.unity.com/threads/simple-udp-implementation-send-read-via-mono-c.15900/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't call Unity API from another Thread. How to use Thread in Unity:

**1**. Start Thread

**2**. Process Input in that new thread

**3**. Tell Unity that you are done processing. You can do this by setting a global `boolean` variable to `true`. Store `output` data in another **global** variable.

**4**. Check if the the `boolean` variable changed in the `Update()` function. Set it `false` if it did. Process output...

Also move `udp = new UdpClient(12345);` from the `Start` function to the `ThreadMethod` function.

```
static readonly object lockObject = new object();
string returnData = "";
bool precessData = false;

void Start ()
{
    cubemove = cube.GetComponent<CubeMove>();
    thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadMethod));
    thread.Start();
}

void Update()
{
    if (precessData)
    {
        /*lock object to make sure there data is 
         *not being accessed from multiple threads at thesame time*/
        lock (lockObject)
        {
            precessData = false;
            cube.SendMessage("Move");
            // or
            cubemove.Move();

            //Process received data
            Debug.Log("Received: " + returnData);

            //Reset it for next read(OPTIONAL)
            returnData = "";
        }
    }
}

private void ThreadMethod()
{
    udp = new UdpClient(12345);
    while (true)
    {
        IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

        byte[] receiveBytes = udp.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);

        /*lock object to make sure there data is 
        *not being accessed from multiple threads at thesame time*/
        lock (lockObject)
        {
            returnData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes);

            Debug.Log(returnData);
            if (returnData == "1\n")
            {
                //Done, notify the Update function
                precessData = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System;

public class UDPRT: ScriptableObject {
 static public string ReceivedMsg; // INPUT DATA
 static private UdpClient udpc;
 static IPEndPoint IP;
 static private object obj;
 static private AsyncCallback AC;
 static byte[] DATA;

 public static UDPRT CreateInstance(int Port) // RECEVE UDP
  {
   IP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, Port);
   udpc = new UdpClient(Port);
   AC = new AsyncCallback(ReceiveIt);
   StartUdpReceive();
   return ScriptableObject.CreateInstance < UDPRT > ();
  }

 public static UDPRT CreateInstance(int Port, string Host, string msg) // SEND UDP
  {
   udpc = new UdpClient(Host, Port);
   AC = new AsyncCallback(SendIt);
   byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msg);
   udpc.BeginSend(data, data.Length, AC, obj);
   return ScriptableObject.CreateInstance < UDPRT > ();
  }

 static void ReceiveIt(IAsyncResult result) {
  DATA = (udpc.EndReceive(result, ref IP));
  Debug.Log(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(DATA));
  ReceivedMsg = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(DATA);
  StartUdpReceive();
 }

 static void SendIt(IAsyncResult result) {
  udpc.EndSend(result);
 }


 static void StartUdpReceive() {
  udpc.BeginReceive(AC, obj);
 }
}
```