# If I'm using UDP with Unity, do I have to make a main loop or can I include the code in Update?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, udp

Just asking if i have to make a main loop within a unity script to hold all the UDP communication stuff or if I can just put it inside update. I'm only calling it once so I don't see a reason to have a separate script.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as main loop. **No**, you can't put your UDP code in the Update function. You either have to use `asynchronous` UDP code or you put your `synchronous` UDP code in a while loop, in [another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37131831/3785314) `Thread`.